# Append div contain a form to edit mysql data on a href click | materialize

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, materialize

I have a table fetching all client information from a database, one of the `<th>` tags contain an edit link, each link contain a unique id matching the specific client of that row.
something like that:

```
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#edit?id=<?php echo $result['idClients']; ?>"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
```

part of the `foreach` loop which displays this table I have a `div` contain a `modal` content in it, in the modal I have a form to update the database.

The loop create an edit form (modal) foreach of the results which results in a lot of code, I would like to find a way to create that `div` only upon clicking the edit icon on the initial table, to save code display on the website. Please correct me if I am wrong and it is the proper way.

Thanks!

index page:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m12">
    <div id="ClientViewer" class="card">
      <div class="card-title">
        <button id="button" type="button" name="button" class="waves-effect waves-gray btn-flat"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i></button>
        <span>title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <table class="striped highlight">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Client Name</th>
              <th>field</th>
              <th>field</th>
              <th>field</th>
              <th>field</th>
              <th>edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
<?php
foreach ($results as $result) {
   ?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $result['clientNameA']. ' and ' .$result['clientNameB']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $result['eventLocation']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $result['eventDate']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $result['clientPackage']; ?></td>
         <td style="color:
        <?php
        $this->checkStatment($result['clientStatus'],'active,'green');
        $this->checkStatment($result['clientStatus'],'temp','#961cf3');
        $this->checkStatment($result['clientStatus'],'archive,'red');
        ;?>;"><?php echo $result['clientStatus']; ?></td>
         <td>
           <a class="modal-trigger" href="#edit?id=<?php echo $result['idClients']; ?>"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
         </td>
       </tr>
   <?php
   include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/admin/resources/pages/_updateclient.php';
}
?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

_updateclient.php page:

```
 <div id="edit?id=<?php echo $result['idClients']; ?>" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4></h4>
    <form id="newclient" class="" action="/admin/resources/php/updateClient" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="row">
          <input type="hidden" name="idClients" value="<?php echo $result['idClients']; ?>" class="validate">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input name="clientNameA" type="text" value="<?php echo $result['clientNameA']; ?>" class="validate">
          <label for="clientNameA"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input name="clientNameB" type="text" value="<?php echo $result['clientNameB']; ?>" class="validate">
          <label for="clientNameB"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input name="clientEmail" type="email" class="validate " value="<?php echo $result['clientEmail']; ?>">
          <label for="clientEmail"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input type="text" name="eventLocation" class="autocomplete" value="<?php echo $result['eventLocation']; ?>">
          <label for="eventLocation"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input name="clientPhone" type="tel" class="validate " value="<?php echo $result['clientPhone']; ?>" >
          <label for="clientPhone"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input name="eventDate" type="text" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo $result['eventDate']; ?>">
          <label for="eventDate"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input name="eventGuests" type="number" class="validate " value="<?php echo $result['eventGuests']; ?>">
          <label for="eventGuests"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <input type="hidden" name="clientStatus" value="">
          <select class="browser-default" name="clientStatus" id="clientStatus">
            <option <?php $this->checkStatment($result['clientStatus'],'active,'selected'); ?> value="active">active</option>
            <option <?php $this->checkStatment($result['clientStatus'],'temp,'selected'); ?> value="temp">temp</option>
            <option <?php $this->checkStatment($result['clientStatus'],'archive,'selected'); ?> value="archive">archive</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
          <select class="browser-default" name="clientPackage" id="clientPackage">
            <option <?php $this->checkStatment($result['clientPackage'],'polo,'selected'); ?> value="polo">polo</option>
            <option <?php $this->checkStatment($result['clientPackage'],'plus,'selected'); ?> value="plus">plus</option>
            <option <?php $this->checkStatment($result['clientPackage'],'plat,'selected'); ?> value="plat">plat</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-default-outline full-width">Update</button>
      </form>
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">close</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Possible answer:

```
 <a data-target="updateClient" href="#updateClient?cs=<?php echo $result['clientStatus'].'&cp='.$result['clientPackage']; ?>" class="modal-trigger waves-effect waves-light"
       data-idclients="<?php echo $result['idClients']; ?>"
       data-clientnamea="<?php echo $result['clientNameA']; ?>"
       data-clientnameb="<?php echo $result['clientNameB']; ?>"
       data-clientemail="<?php echo $result['clientEmail']; ?>"
       data-eventlocation="<?php echo $result['eventLocation']; ?>"
       data-clientphone="<?php echo $result['clientPhone']; ?>"
       data-eventdate="<?php echo $result['eventDate']; ?>"
       data-eventguests="<?php echo $result['eventGuests']; ?>"
       data-clientstatus="<?php echo $result['clientStatus']; ?>"

       ><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>

    $('.modal').modal({
    onOpenStart: function(modal, trigger) {
    $(modal).find('input[name="idClients"]').val($(trigger).data('idclients'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="clientNameA"]').val($(trigger).data('clientnamea'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="clientNameB"]').val($(trigger).data('clientnameb'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="clientEmail"]').val($(trigger).data('clientemail'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="eventLocation"]').val($(trigger).data('eventlocation'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="clientPhone"]').val($(trigger).data('clientphone'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="eventDate"]').val($(trigger).data('eventdate'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="eventGuests"]').val($(trigger).data('eventguests'))
            $(modal).find('input[name="eventSuests"]').val($(trigger).data('eventstatus'))
            var eventstatus = ($(trigger).data('eventstatus'));
            $.post('resources/pages/_updateclient.php', {eventstatus: eventstatus});
}
```

Few things, I can not pass `val eventstatus` with `$.post`. And second is that all the values in the form are set on top of the label of the input field, solution?

Comment: I do this all the time - you have one single modal in the footer and then in your loop, each item would have the same trigger. Use data-attributes to attach data to each item, then on click, you would collect all the data and then dynamically populate the modal. Don't forget to clear the modal each time. If you don't know how to do this, I'll build you a codepen but it sounds like you know what you are doing - and you're definitely thinking along the right line that outputting a modal for each one is overkill.

Comment: Edited to a possible solution.

Comment: Well..did it work?! :)

Comment: For the most part!, thanks a lot I can pass the data but in the select field I got a function to check what field is been pulled from the data base to echo active in that field. How can I pass this data and use is a php variable? As well, looks like the data pass into the field on top of the field label, I tried use active on those label but it’s not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't 100% understand your issue, could you maybe screenshot what the output is and maybe that will help.

Comment: Sure! https://ibb.co/MBNncHj 
What about passing a variable to reuse it as a PHP variable, any good ideas? 
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: That looks like you just need to add a class of active to the label and a class of valid to each input

Comment: It is not working, value field has to have information for that to work. The data-attribute does not pass the data into the value field of the form (<input value="") .
I was thinking of passing all the data in a $.post with var, cache it after in the form with $_POST['']. How would I do that?

Comment: Anyone with any good idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The above possible answer worked for me, just use an empty `placeholder=""` to allow active class work.